# Mismatched base32 encoded hash of certificate

Tags: java, android, hash, certificate, guava

[Syncthing](https://github.com/calmh/syncthing) uses the following Go code to compute a "Node ID," a base32 encoded SHA256 hash of an SSL certificate:

```
func certID(bs []byte) string {
    hf := sha256.New()
    hf.Write(bs)
    id := hf.Sum(nil)
    return strings.Trim(base32.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(id), "=")
}
```

As far as I can tell, the certificate is [just passed in](https://github.com/calmh/syncthing/blob/20b23338f780f5d327855776b452981339dde15f/cmd/syncthing/main.go#L573) as raw bytes:

```
 // ...
    remoteID := certID(certs[0].Raw)
 // ...
```

I have tried to replicate this in Java (I'm somewhat new to Java), using the following method:

```
public static String ComputeSTNodeID(Certificate cert) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256");
    return BaseEncoding.base32().encode(md.digest(cert.getEncoded())).replaceAll("=", "");
}
```

(`BaseEncoding` is borrowed from Google's Guava library.)

For a given certificate, the calculations are different:

```
Go:   T2JOFPRO7UJB4YHXOSCY4U4YQEFLFI355JQKRD7ZB2ZLEPU6RD4Q
Java: HMKJKSJPB7CM54YHMYIFAN5F7MZAHOFXX4XG5SQWAZLY4I4ROJFA
```

What am I doing wrong?  @fge and I have worked out that the `.getEncoded()` call is not returning the same thing as what is contained in the Go `.Raw` member.

Comment: If you are using Guava you should also consider using `Hashing` instead of `MessageDigest`

Comment: Any particular reason why?  This is ultimately going on Android, and the smaller the binary is, the better.

Comment: Because Guava just works? ;) Honestly, you should really consider it; and it will ultimately be more portable since the Guava implementation remains the same whatever the JRE!

Comment: There are two `Certificate`s in the JDK; java.security's and javax.security.cert's. Which one do you use?

Comment: I'm using `java.security.cert.Certificate`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you try Go's base32 against Guava's for a same byte array, do you obtain the same results?

Comment: I do obtain the same results (after much, much swearing at Java's classpath):  The bytes `abc123!@#` encode to `MFRGGMJSGMQUAIY=` on both.

Comment: Therefore the problem is with the cert's `.getEncoded()` part which does not return the same thing on both. Well, at least this will have narrowed the problem space ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not really a full answer but using Guava you can make your life easier by using a `Hasher` instead of `MessageDigest`.

Why? Because `Hasher` extends `PrimitiveSink`, which means you can create a `Funnel` for `Certificate`; you'll only have to change the `Funnel` to get that part right!

Illustration:

```
public enum CertificateFunnel
    implements Funnel<Certificate>
{
    INSTANCE
    {
        @Override
        public void funnel(final Certificate from, final PrimitiveSink into)
        {
            into.putBytes(from.getEncoded());
        }
    }
}
```

You would then have a `private static final HashFunction SHA256`:

```
private static final HashFunction SHA256 = Hashing.sha256();
```

And also a `private static final BaseEncoding BASE32_NOPAD` since instances of `BaseEncoding` are thread safe and immutable:

```
private static final BaseEncoding BASE32_NOPAD
    = BaseEncoding.base32().omitPadding(); // No need to strip `=`!
```

You would then feed the certificate with:

```
final Hasher hasher = SHA256.newHasher();

// Funnel the certificate...
hasher.putObject(certificate, CertificateFunnel.INSTANCE);

// Then encode
return BASE32_NOPAD.encode(hasher.hashCode().asBytes());
```

Just my .02 bitcoins.

Comment: The Go routine strips the `=`s because they appear at the end of the Base32 form.

Comment: Ah yeah, padding; but given the length, is there really padding? that looks rather contrived

Comment: It's just how he did it, and I would like to duplicate it.  It makes it look nicer anyway, since the output will always be the same length.

Comment: Also, `BaseEncoding` instances are immutable ;)

Comment: If you're just hashing the certificate, you could just do `Hashing.sha256().hashObject(certificate, CertificateFunnel.INSTANCE).asBytes()` to get the hashed bytes.

Comment: Or could avoid the funnel by just doing: `Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(certificate.getEncoded()).asBytes()`.

Comment: @ColinD that's the thing; if `.getEncoded()` is not what is needed, you can just change the `Funnel`; if you shortcut this way, you are condemned to a refactoring if `.getEncoded()` is not what you want

Comment: @fge: Yes, it just depends on how many different places in your code you need to be doing this... if it's just one place anyway (e.g. one method that creates a base32 string), the funnel doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @ColinD yes, that is true; but on the other hand it doesn't hurt, does it? ;)

Comment: @fge: I dunno... YAGNI and all. Add a funnel if and when you need it, not before IMO.

Comment: @ColinD the `PrimitiveSink` interface pretty much compels you to use a `Funnel` for anything not "primitive", appropriately enough; only when you are sure that you can reliably stuff primitives do you do so. That is the beauty of this interface as far as I see it.

Comment: @fge: Stuff like `Hashing.sha256().newHasher().putInt(i).putBytes(b).hash()` is a pretty common pattern for hashing that doesn't require a funnel (`Hasher` is a `PrimitiveSink` itself of course).

Comment: @fge: It's actually very readable if you split it across multiple lines as is typically done. And you don't have to create the whole funnel implementation.

Comment: @ColinD which makes me think you don't really understand why the `Funnel` is here in the first place! Again: if you have to "funnel" the certificate in a different way, you only have to change the funnel itself!

Comment: @fge: I'm well aware of why `Funnel` is there in the first place. It's so that if you have a Java type that you need to hash the same way in multiple places, you can create a reusable way to do that. If you're only hashing this thing in one place, it really doesn't matter at all if you have a `Funnel` or not. Anyway, I didn't mean to make this into a big debate... it's not a big deal either way.

Comment: @ColinD "If you're only hashing this thing in one place, it really doesn't matter at all if you have a Funnel or not." this is where I disagree ;) Have a look [here](https://github.com/parboiled1/grappa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/parboiled1/grappa/transform) for instance. This is the kind of thing I love to debate :p Sorry ;)